# Problema com datas em PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho esta query abaixo e quero que o `faturamento`, `ticket_medio` e `qtd_pecas`, `qtd_atendimentos`, sejam divididos pelos números de terças-feiras. 
Exemplo teve 5 terça feiras com valores registrados nessa view, quero que seja dividido por 5.

Qual função do postgres posso utilizar?

```
SELECT
    id_empresa,
    id_loja,
    sum(faturamento),
    sum(ticket_medio),
    sum(qtd_pecas),
    sum(qtd_atendimentos)
FROM
    sumario_diario
WHERE
    to_char(data_sumario, 'dy') = 'tue'
    AND id_loja = 19
GROUP BY
    id_empresa,
    id_loja;
```

Comment: Poderia anexar um exemplo de como esses dados estão armazenados e como desejaria que fosse retornado no SQL? Acredito que ficaria mais claro para o pessoal da comunidade ajudar.

Comment: @CamiloSantos eu respondi a pergunta e criei um exemplo, veja aqui: [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228091/problema-com-datas-em-postgresql/228136#228136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir encontrar a resposta, ficou desta maneira:

```
SELECT  id_empresa, id_loja, avg(faturamento), avg(ticket_medio), avg(qtd_pecas),avg(qtd_atendimentos) FROM sumario_diario
```

where TO_CHAR(data_sumario, 'dy') = 'tue'
and id_loja = 19
group by id_empresa, id_loja

Answer (score 0):

## Veja se isto resolve

```
SELECT
    id_empresa,
    id_loja,
    sum(faturamento),
    sum(ticket_medio),
    sum(qtd_pecas),
    sum(qtd_atendimentos),

    avg(faturamento) as fat_terca,
    avg(ticket_medio) as ticket_terca,
    avg(qtd_pecas) as pecas_terca,
    avg(qtd_atendimentos) as aten_terca

FROM
    sumario_diario
WHERE
    to_char(data_sumario, 'dy') = 'tue'
    AND id_loja = 19
GROUP BY
    id_empresa,
    id_loja;
```

**[Clique aqui para executar o Teste!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2561e/11)**

Comment: @CamiloSantos aqui minha resposta com exemplo.